# Can I use start_urls to scrape a url list?

Tags: scrapy

I have a url list that I want to scrape data from. It's from a database that I want to update but I'm unsure as to how to proceed.

```
import scrapy
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class A1hrlaterSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'onehrlater'
    allowed_domains = ['donedeal.ie']
    timenow = datetime.now()
    delta = timedelta(minutes=0)
    delta2 = timedelta(minutes=1)
    past_time = timenow - delta
    past_time2 = timenow - delta2
    conn = sqlite3.connect('ddother.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT adUrl FROM database WHERE timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ?", (past_time2, past_time))
    all_urls = c.fetchall()
    urllist = [item[0] for item in all_urls]

    print(urllist)

    conn.commit()

    conn.close()
```

Urllist is the list of urls I want to scrape. But I'm not sure how I use start_urls to
follow the links or if indeed this is the right way to go about it. Can I say start_urls = urllist or is this wrong?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Look into `start_requests`.

Comment: ok I will, thanks Gallaecio